# Adding rich text column with formatting to library

Tags: 2013, document-library, richhtmlfield

Out of the box it seems you can't have a rich text column in a document library with SP 2013 -- I have no idea why, but [it seems to be the case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/67a70245-cd03-48e1-b0fa-71bbb6a7744d/is-enhanced-rich-text-column-supported-by-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy).

We have worked around this by going into SP Designer, finding the Library, Edit List Columns and ticking the boxes for Rich and Enhanced text. This allows a custom column in that library to have rich text. I can't find the original page that suggested this fix, but we have been using it for quite awhile now. So far, so good.

When the user clicks in that text box they get the fancy editing controls in the ribbon and they work...except the **Styles** group. In that case only the **Page elements** section (paragraph, h1, h2, etc.) show up.

The text styles section (normal, quote, accent 1, etc.) doesn't show up at all.

I've been trying to add some custom styles to the ribbon, but haven't been successful because of the trick to get rich text into a document library.

Any suggestions for how to implement this? Probably we are just out of luck since this is a hack already, but I have to ask.

Is there a way to just bypass all of this SP silliness?

Comment: I know it's late but this helped me to enable the rich text field features. [Why aren't the editing tools available when I am editing a “Multiple lines of text” field allowing rich text?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46107/why-arent-the-editing-tools-available-when-i-am-editing-a-multiple-lines-of-te)