# Creating a page template based on a content type: why the multiple lines field becomes a max 255 field?

Tags: content-type, multiline-text-field

I am following a guide to create a page template (from article page) starting from a content type.

The majority of fields are multiple lines of text and some of them are at 3 lines, 6 or 10. When I create a page based on my template, I compile the fields and when I publish the page I get on pretty much every field that it can contain not more than 255.

What do I have to do to render my fields as multiple lines of text? Also all the fields were set in the content type as with formatting available, while in the page they allow me to write only plain text.

This is the screenshot of the relative site column. I have switched Unlimited length in libraries to yes but I am still not getting the formatting
[image]

Comment: Is it perhaps a Site Content Type - in which case it might be using Site Columns.  They might default to have the 255 character limit.  I think a List Column can be customised, perhaps a Site Column can to - but then the changes you make would cascade throughout the site collection to any areas that are using the Site Columns.

Comment: see above, now it gives me more characters, but still i do not see the formatting bar when i am writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized that there is the column called Full HTML content with formatting and constraints for publishing that accomplishes what I want: multiline text with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a read through [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46107/why-arent-the-editing-tools-available-when-i-am-editing-a-multiple-lines-of-te?rq=1), it poses a very similar issue to your own and provides a step-by-step answer.

It involves creating a new site column, site content type, a new document library and a document library template.  It's a little different to your issue, since yours involves pages, but it appears to be a field issue rather than something specific to Sharepoint pages.